# $\int_0^{\infty} \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} x_m \left( \varepsilon \right) e^{- \varepsilon} \mathrm{d} \varepsilon$

Tags: limits, roots, exponential-function

In the expression

$$\int_0^{\infty} \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} x_m \left( \varepsilon \right)
e^{- \varepsilon} \mathrm{d} \varepsilon$$

Is it possible to move the integral inside the Newton's iteration?

$$x_{i + 1} \left( \varepsilon \right) = x_i \left( \varepsilon \right) -
\frac{f \left( x_i \left( \varepsilon \right) \right)}{f' \left( x_i \left(
\varepsilon \right) \right)}$$

Comment: To do something like this you'll generally need to satisfy the assumptions of the [Dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [Dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) or [monotone convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) for exchanging limits and integrals. That is, either:

- $x_m(\epsilon)e^{-\epsilon}\le x_{m+1}(\epsilon)e^{-\epsilon} \forall \epsilon\ \forall m$ (or)
- There should exist an integrable function $f(\epsilon)$ such that $x_m(\epsilon)\le f(\epsilon)\ \forall \epsilon\ \forall m$.

Comment: You should say that the function $f(\epsilon)$ must be integrable.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: thanks, edited.